# Sort alphabetically in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe

```
Counties                        Numbers
Yabucoa Municipio, Puerto Rico  7766
Marion County, West Virginia    8756
Barbour County, Alabama         33445
Santa Cruz County, Arizona      447
Navajo County, Arizona          1500
Denver County, Colorado         67990
```

I'm trying to sort in a way such that the state names are alphabetically sorted and the county names are internally sorted within the state

```
Counties                        Numbers
Barbour County, Alabama         33445
Navajo County, Arizona          1500
Santa Cruz County, Arizona      447
Denver County, Colorado         67990
Yabucoa Municipio, Puerto Rico  7766
Marion County, West Virginia    8756
```

Dataframe code:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Counties': 'Yabucoa Municipio, Puerto Rico','Numbers': 7766},
    {'Counties': 'Marion County, West Virginia','Numbers': 8756},
    {'Counties': 'Barbour County, Alabama','Numbers': 33445},
    {'Counties': 'Santa Cruz County, Arizona','Numbers': 447},
    {'Counties': 'Navajo County, Arizona','Numbers': 1500},
    {'Counties': 'Denver County, Colorado','Numbers': 67990}
])
```

I have tried it using `sort` and `split` code but it doesn't give the desired output

```
df_test['Counties'] = df_test['Counties'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(sorted(x.split(','))))
```

What should be done? Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*an* approach to this could be the following:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"Counties": "Yabucoa Municipio, Puerto Rico", "Numbers": 7766},
        {"Counties": "Marion County, West Virginia", "Numbers": 8756},
        {"Counties": "Barbour County, Alabama", "Numbers": 33445},
        {"Counties": "Santa Cruz County, Arizona", "Numbers": 447},
        {"Counties": "Navajo County, Alabama", "Numbers": 1500},
        {"Counties": "Denver County, Colorado", "Numbers": 67990},
    ]
)
```

Then create a key to reorder by:

```py
re_order_key = (
    df["Counties"]
    .str.split(",", expand=True)
    .rename(columns={0: "county", 1: "state"})
    .sort_values(by=["state", "county"])
)
```

Use this index with iloc:

```py
df.iloc[re_order.index, :].reset_index(drop=True)
```

which gives:

```py
                         Counties  Numbers
0         Barbour County, Alabama    33445
1          Navajo County, Alabama     1500
2      Santa Cruz County, Arizona      447
3         Denver County, Colorado    67990
4  Yabucoa Municipio, Puerto Rico     7766
5    Marion County, West Virginia     8756
```

Comment: note to OP - I feel there's a better approach than the above, so encourage them to wait a little as someone is likely to provide something nicer.